# Beeware Toga confirm_dialog callback error

Tags: python, callback, beeware, confirm-dialog

I am trying to use the `confirm_dialog` window with Beeware. I understand that the `on_result` callback should be activated only when I click the `OK` button. Below i attach a simple script I use to try it. The `confirm_dialog` window pops-up ok, but when i click either the `OK` or the `cancel` button i get the error `func2() takes 1 positional argument but 3 were given`. I tried both in `dev` mode and in `run android`, and got the same issue. It looks to me that the problem is in the callback, but I could not find a way of making it work. I would much appreciate any answer or hint on what I am doing wrong.

**UPDATE:** I corrected the code below according to the answer by `gimix` that solved the problem. Now the code works just fine.

```
import toga
from toga.style import Pack
from toga.style.pack import COLUMN, ROW
class HelloWorld(toga.App):

    def startup(self):   
        main_box = toga.Box(style=Pack(direction=COLUMN))
        record_button = toga.Button("func1",on_press=self.func1,style=Pack(padding=5))
        main_box.add(record_button)

        self.main_window = toga.MainWindow(title=self.formal_name)
        self.main_window.content = main_box

    def func2(self,dialog,result):
        print("callback worked")

    def func1(self,widget):
        self.main_window.confirm_dialog("title", "message",on_result=self.func2)
        return 

def main():
    return HelloWorld()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not a Toga expert, but I had a look at the definition of `ConfirmDialog` and its superclass `MessageDialog`, where your callback gets called:

```
        # def completion_handler(self, return_value: bool) -> None:
        if self.on_result:
            self.on_result(self, result)
```

As you can see `func2` is called with 3 arguments: `self` (your class), the `self` of the dialog (i.e. the dialog object), and finally the return value of the dialog. So the definition should be something like

```
def func2(self, dialog, result):
    #do something
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your helpful answer. Works perfectly.